# JsonWriter и zipOutputStream как связать?

Tags: java, android

Хочу с помощью класса JsonWriter организовать запись в файл, хранящийся в zip-архиве, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение, все оказалось очень просто, вот строка кода:

```
JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(zipOutputStream, "UTF-8"));
```